# asp.net Row Count VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So I want to count the rows of the items that I can currently see in the gridview after filtering with a Drop Down List.

If I select a new item it displays the count of the previous value I selected

Example, I select Beamer in the DDL and it has 4 items in it but before that I selected Copier and that one had 8 items in it, after selecting Beamer my label will show the 8 from the copier and so on.

My Code:

```
Protected Sub ddlType_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlType.TextChanged

    Dim intAantal As Integer = gvRapportObjecten.Rows.Count
    lblAantal.Text = "Het aantal items is: " & intAantal.ToString
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvo8S.png)

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="GridDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LPIProjectConnection %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT object.id, object.label, object.object_type, object_type.name FROM object_type LEFT JOIN [object] ON object_type.id = object.object_type" FilterExpression="name  = '{0}'">
<FilterParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="name" ControlID="ddlType" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
</FilterParameters>
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I dont get an error, it's just I need the 5 to be displayed and not the 11 from the previous selection

Comment: When is the data changed in the grid?

Comment: I mean you have data bound to it, or you change it manually?

Comment: I have data bound to it, after I select a new value in the Drop Down List the gridview changes the data

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that the code on the `ddlType_SelectedIndexChanged` event its executed before your datafilter, so you change the value on the ddl, it counts the current rows on your gridview and then updates the gridview.
You need to move your code after your Gridview `DataBind()`

Comment: To be sure that the GridView has been updated, that piece of code could be in the `PreRender` event.

Comment: Thx ConnorsFan, the PreRender did it for me!

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview_events(v=vs.110).aspx) all the events of grid view

I see you have used `selectedindexchanged` event. This event occurs AFTER the grid is loaded. You should use `selectedindexchanging` event instead which is fired BEFORE the grid is loaded.

I hope this helps.